# mssql syntax error near the keyword 'in'

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, iif

When i execute below query in sql server i got below error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'

Query:

```
select projectid 
from projects 
where iif(1!=1,
projects.projectid in (1,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23),
1);
```

Comment: Please tag your question correctly.  `iif()` is not a MySQL function and not a typical SQL Server function (you would use `case` in SQL Server; `iif()` provides compatibility for MS Access).  Also, your logic makes little sense, because "1 <> 1" is always false.

Comment: sorry my mistake it is mssql

Comment: here i got description of iif()                                                                    link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

Explanation: you cannot use IN operator in THEN part of CASE Statement, that's why use nested CASE statements. Now, this query will give you no record because "1 != 1" always returns false and THEN part will not execute.

```
SELECT projectid

FROM projects

WHERE
projectid = CASE

        WHEN 1 != 1 

        THEN 

            CASE 
            WHEN projectid IN (1,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)
            THEN projectid
            ELSE 1 END
      END;
```

Now, there is no syntax error near IN keyword. You can modify this query according to your requirement.

Comment: Same as: `WHERE 1 != 1 AND projectid IN (1, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23) OR  1  = 1 AND projectid = 1`

Comment: can you tell me that projectid = Case Statement,but can i use only case statement not projectid ?

Comment: In Where clause you have to mention column name to match the resultant project id. OR you can use this
SELECT CASE
   WHEN 1 != 1 
   THEN 
    CASE 
    WHEN projectid IN (1,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)
    THEN projectid
    ELSE 0 END
     END
FROM projects p

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent logic is:

```
select p.projectid 
from projects p
where (1 = 1) or p.projectid in (1, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23);
```

However, this is overkill, because the first expression involves only constants and is always true.  More commonly, you would have something like:

```
where (@TakeAllFlag = 1) or p.projectid in (1, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23);
```

Also, if you are learning SQL -- and not using MS Access -- learn the `CASE` statement, not `IIF()`.  `CASE` is standard SQL and available in basically all databases.

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

```
select projectid 
from projects 
where projects.projectid in (1,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)
```

Don't see any sense of putting an `IIF` function in the where clause.

```
 iif(1!=1, projects.projectid in (1,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23), 1)
```

In simple English the above line interoperates as `if 1 is not equal to 1 then use the IN expression else return 1`

1 is always equal to 1 and the rest doesn't make any sense .

Comment: This is only example, but i want to use sub query in where clause and here 1!=1 condition will change this is not fix. it may be like iif(company_id != 1) so here if expression is true than  IN clause should execute but SQL gives error like Incorrect Syntax near 'IN' ?

Comment: Ok even in this case use of `IIF` statement is invalid in where clause, IIF will return the first value if the expression is evaluated to true or 2nd if false, in either case IIF will return a value, in `WHERE` clause you need an expression which will be evaluated for each row returned by the query, IIF will return only one value not an expression, so sql server doesn't know what to do with it and errors out.

Comment: You can use IIF in where clause something like `WHERE 1 = IIF(<some expression> , 1 , 0)`